# Storage account FileShare Can I mount as Drive

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-account

Hi Have below questions.

I have a storage account and inside storage account, I have file shares.
And below is my folder structure

```
Root\Account 1
Root\Account 1\ReadOnly
Root\Account 1\ReadAndWrite
Root\Account 2
Root\Account 2\ReadOnly
Root\Account 2\ReadAndWrite
```

Now my questions are can I map my End users with `Root\Account 2\ReadOnly or Root\Account 2\ReadAndWrite` as their network-connected shared Drive “z:\”

I was actually trying with https://husseinsalman.com/securing-access-to-azure-storage-part-5-stored-access-policy/ blog post, here What I do not understand is the how to give SAS Signature to mount as a network folder ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to mount the specific directory, however you can set permission to files and directory.You can check [Azure Active Directory Domain Services authentication on Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable?tabs=azure-portal) assign permission for the directories

[Azure Files identity-based authentication options for SMB access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview)

[Configure directory and file level permissions over SMB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-configure-permissions)

If you mount the file share by using SMB, you don't have folder-level control over permissions. However, if you create a shared access signature by using the REST API or client libraries, you can specify read-only or write-only permissions on folders within the share.